# siunitx and missing decimal point

Tags: siunitx

\si seems to be not showing decimal points, unless I specifically specify \num.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\si{12.5\milli\gram}

\si{\num{12.5}\milli\gram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: You are using the wrong command: `\SI{12.5}{\milli\gram}` is what you want. The `\si` command is for units and treats `.` as a separator (inherited from older packages in the area).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\si{units}` is for **units only**. You have to use the `\SI{number}{units}` for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I guess i am replying really late for your query, but you should use `\num` directly and not nest it in `\si`.

For a number

```
\num{12.5}
```

and `\SI` (in upper case) for a number with a unit

```
\SI{12.5}{\milli\gram}
```